# How do I fix an Internal Server Error on a WordPress multisite network?

Tags: wordpress

I am using a Multisite network with two sites. The first site is working fine, but the second throws an error 500 whenever I try to access the dashboard. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) WordPress_SecureMode_01/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ WordPress_SecureMode_01/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I would like to know if there is a fix on this file, or failing that some potential fixes in other files. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the **WordPress_SecureMode_01** comes from, but did you try the sample from [Wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)?

Are you using Nginx or Apache?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the server have correct permissions to access the files?  One common cause of HTTP 500 errors could be running apache/nginx and trying to serve files/content that these services do not have read access to.  You might try checking owner/group permissions of the files and double-check that your server service is also included in the owner/group as this might be the cause.